# Unicode characters causing 404 error in file_get_contents()

Tags: php, url, domcrawler

I have an app visiting URLs automatically through links. It works good as long as the URL doesn't contain Unicode.

For example, I have a link:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/catalog/kraków/list.html">Kraków</a>
```

The link contains just pure ó character in the source. When I try to do:

```php
$href = $crawler->filter('a')->attr('href');
$html = file_get_contents($href);
```

It returns 404 error. If I visit that URL in the browser, it's fine, because the browser replaces ó to %C3%B3.

What should I do to make is possible to visit that URL via `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097744/file-get-contents-fails-with-special-characters-in-url ?

Answer (score 1):

[urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) can be used to encode url parts. The following snippet extracts the path `/catalog/kraków/list.html` and encodes the contents: `catalog`, `kraków` and `list.html` instead of the entire url to preserve the path.

Checkout the following solution:

```
function encodeUri($uri){
    $urlParts = parse_url($uri);

    $path = implode('/', array_map(function($pathPart){
        return strpos($pathPart, '%') !== false ? $pathPart : urlencode($pathPart);
    },explode('/', $urlParts['path'])));

    $query = array_key_exists('query', $urlParts) ? '?' . $urlParts['query'] : '';

    return $urlParts['scheme'] . '://' . $urlParts['host']  . $path . $query;
}


$href = $crawler->filter('a')->attr('href');
$html = file_get_contents(encodeUri($href)); // outputs: https://example.com/catalog/krak%C3%B3w/list.html
```

parse_url docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: It loses query string. I understand the idea and I'm going to implement it on the path part of the URL.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the query path :) @RoboRobok

Comment: Now it causes error on missing query string and adds (in theory) redundant `?` if there's no query.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it @RoboRobok

Comment: It looks better and better, but you know. Then there's port etc. Also, if the URL is already encoded, it will cause trouble too. Isn't there any better way?

Comment: Fair points, the port requirement are easy to implement using the `parse_url` method. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php. I added a safe guard for double encoding @RoboRobok

Comment: That condition is not always good. Query string can be urlencoded and the path not, for example.

Comment: Ah you are right, moved it to the Query string, urlencoding the domain is not supported in http so that edge case doesn't have to be covered. @RoboRobok